# Criar campo de senha no django

Tags: python, django

Queria conseguir criar um campo de senha com os asteriscos e fazer um hash da senha salva no banco de dados por questões de segurança.

```
class Cliente(models.Model):    
    cpf = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11, editable=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer o hash da senha basta utilizar a função helper que o Django oferece para isso. É a função [`make_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/passwords/)

Ela vai criar um hash para uma senha passada como parâmetro e se for passado o valor `None` então será gerado uma senha não utilizável.

Você já implementou o Model Cliente, para criar um novo usuário podemos utilizar a função citada acima, e para exibir um asterisco no form, basta trocar o [`widget`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/) do `CharField` para o [`PasswordInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput) utilizando um ModelForm para a sua classe de Modelo. No ClienteForm estou explicitamente configurando o atributo `senha` para que o formulário renderizado possua o input `type="password"`. A maneira de fazer isso no Django é passando o widget `widget=forms.PasswordInput`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Cliente

class ClienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    senha = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = '__all__'
```

Depois no arquivo `views.py` você deve utilizar a classe ClienteForm que acabou de criar.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .forms import  ClienteForm
from .models import Cliente
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

def subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return create(request)
    else:
        return new(request)

def new(request):
    return render(request, 'cliente/cliente_form.html', {'form': ClienteForm()})

def create(request):
    form = ClienteForm(request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid():
       return render(request, 'cliente/cliente_form.html', {'form': form})

    c = form.save(commit=False)
    c.senha = make_password(c.senha)
    c.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Os nomes referênciados como `cliente/cliente_form.html` são hipotéticos, e devem representar um arquivo .html válido no mapeamento de templates da sua aplicação.

Uma página html que contém este form poderia ser escrita como:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <p>
        <label for="{{ form.nome.id_for_label }}">{{ form.nome.label }}:</label>
        {{ form.nome }}
        {{ form.nome.errors }}
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="{{ form.cpf.id_for_label }}">{{ form.cpf.label }}:</label>
        {{ form.cpf }}
        {{ form.cpf.errors }}
    </p>
    <p> 
        <label for="{{ form.senha.id_for_label }}">{{ form.senha.label }}:</label>
        {{ form.senha }}
        {{ form.senha.errors }}
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="button">
</form>
```

Repare que estou fazendo o `HttpResponseRedirect` para a url `/` mas você pode ter uma página estática de criação de cliente com sucesso. Pode adaptar a solução para seu caso de uso.

Outro trecho que devo destacar é o fato de haver um form.save(commit=False) essa função vai retornar um objeto (válido), antes de fazer a persistência dos valores no banco de dados desejamos fazer o hash da senha, é o que a função make_password está fazendo. Depois disso basta sobre-escrever o atributo `senha` e terá a sua lógica completa.

Ao chamar o método `c.save()` a coluna  `senha` na tabela `cliente` possuirá um valor parecido com este:

```
bkdf2_sha256$20000$o1Mb8FuprOSw$MkXWwh896am1cVsNT1UxCsTffA4crk2ZpUAp0PJSb/w=
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela resposta! Estou adaptando para meu caso pois não estou utilizando html, mas de qualquer forma ajudou muito!!!!