# Senha cadastrada fica como invalida no Django

Tags: html, python, django

Essa é a view que faz o cadastro de usuários:

```
 def cadastrar_usuario(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        nome_usuario = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        newUser = User.objects.create(username = nome_usuario, email = email, password = password)
        newUser.save()

        return redirect('login')

    template = loader.get_template('registration/register.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))
```

Ao cadastrar um novo usuário a senha não é salva e fica como invalida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Criar campo de senha no django](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/542514/criar-campo-de-senha-no-django)

Answer (score -1):

Para resolver este problema é necessário utilizar a função helper `makepassword`.

Isso fará senha ser armazenada em um formato que respeita o algoritmo de hash utilizado pelo Django.

O seu código será assim:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
# ...
def cadastrar_usuario(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        nome_usuario = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        hashed_pwd = make_password(password)
        newUser = User.objects.create(username = nome_usuario, email = email, password = hashed_pwd)
        newUser.save()    
        return redirect('login')

    template = loader.get_template('registration/register.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))
```

Para mais informações sobre como gerenciar senhas consulte a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/4.0/topics/auth/passwords/), seção: `Manually managing a user’s password`.

---

Vi que você está acesssando os atributos do form diretamente, isso é uma má prática e deve ser evitado, o correto seria criar um objeto herda de [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/), caso seja um form temporário, ou utilizar um modelform, caso deseje interagir com um formulário que representa uma entidade em seu modelo.

Isso é bom porque pode utilizar validações dos atributos de maneira nativa, sem a necessidade de criar lógicas complicadas.

Assim antes de criar uma nova entidade, basta verificar se o form é válido e já ganhará a validação dos atributos.

Caso o formulário não seja válido poderá renderizar o formulário com as mensagens da validação (os atributos inválidos)  e os campos válidos já preenchidos. Um exemplo completo de como pode fazer isso pode ser visto nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/542540/103217).

Answer (score -4):

Tente passa-lá codificada: password.encode()

Ou

Use algum hash recomendo o MD5, link para auxiliar a utilização:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/md5-hash-python/
é bem simples.